How to Implement Custom SSO with SAML for Multiple Web Apps?
I want to implement Single Sign-On (SSO) using SAML for three web applications:

aaa.myweb.com
bbb.myweb.com
ccc.myweb.com

These are distinct React-based applications, each serving different content, but they share a single backend. Here's my setup:

Backend: Custom-built in Golang using the GoChi framework.

Hosts RESTful APIs, including authentication endpoints.
Manages all user data directly.


Database: PostgreSQL, containing all user data and other content.
Authentication Requirement:

Centralised login for all three applications.
Use email and password for login when the user is not authenticated.



Goal:
I aim to implement SSO using SAML, but I want to build a custom Identity Provider (IdP) using my backend. I prefer not to use third-party services like Okta, OneLogin, OAuth etc.
Challenges:

I couldn't find detailed resources or articles explaining the implementation of SAML SSO in this kind of custom setup.
I’m specifically looking for guidance or a workflow on how to build SAML SSO with Golang, but insights or examples in other languages would also be helpful.

Can someone provide a complete workflow with code and setup or resources to help achieve this? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Don't re-invent the wheel! you can use open source projects like: keycloak zitadel authentik , take a look at this list
